# what is http/dl protocol in wireshark?

Tags: http, protocols, wireshark

I'm using wireshark to analyze network packet.

I found weird packet that contains data, such as 0xaa.

The packet was http/dl protocol.

how does the protocol work?

Comment: I can't find any "http/dl" protocol in Wireshark.  Could you please either post your capture file, or a screenshot of the capture, somewhere, so we can see what Wireshark is saying?